# Excel VBA: chr-function error when using value > 255

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to print the lambda (λ) character using following code:

```
depug.print chr(964)
```

I looked up the specific value for lambda for the chr-function [here](http://www.vba-wiki.net/index.php?title=Zeichentabelle). Unfortunately I get a Runtime-Error 5 with the information that it is an invalid value.

I found out this seems to appear using values over 255.

**Now I am curious**, how to print that lambda character? Respectively any other greek character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
 ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H3BB)
```

credit: https://www.w3.org/Math/characters/html/symbol.html
just replace `00` with `&H`

This thread also shows a link to a unicode converter 
[Special characters(letters) in excel VBA (čćžšđ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418058/special-charactersletters-in-excel-vba-%C4%8D%C4%87%C5%BE%C5%A1%C4%91)

Comment: I tried that code and got a "?"... Does it depend which Excel-version I am using (2016)

Comment: I dont think you can print it in the "immediate" window... i updated my answer to just displaying it in the excel sheet