# Get Unicode characters with charcode values greater hex `FFFF`

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

**Issue**

The `ChrW` charcode argument is a `Long` that identifies a character, but doesn't allow values greater than 65535 (hex value `&HFFFF`) -
see [MS Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chr-function).

For instance **Miscellaneous symbols and pictographs** can be found at *Unicode hex block* `1F300-1F5FF`. So I didn't find *any way* to represent the proposed hex values of ►`1F512` and `1F513` for a opened or closed **padlock symbol**
precisely in *this charcode block*, as of Course `ChrW(&H1F512)` would result in an invalid procedure/argument call.

*A recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56004536/padlock-symbol-through-vba) found an possibly erratic alternative referring to a **lower charcode** 
(via `ChrW(&HE1F7)` and `ChrW(&HE1F6)`), but I'm searching for a way to get the higher charcode representation.*

**Question**

Is there a systematic way to express **Unicode characters** found in hexadecimal code blocks greater than `FFFF` by means of VBA or a work around?

Comment: For the sake of (assumed) completeness - added a further approach to all the valid and great answers here demonstrating the ►`FilterXML` function (introduced in Excel 2013).

Comment: Related: [Alternative of ChrW function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57158679/11683)

Comment: Thx for completing this set of valid answers. @Gserg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work. Most code I didn't write, but I knew what to look for. Basically map the Hex to the byte array equivalent, then get the string back.

```
 Option Explicit

'Pulled from https://www.di-mgt.com.au/howto-convert-vba-unicode-to-utf8.html
''' Maps a character string to a UTF-16 (wide character) string
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MultiByteToWideChar Lib "kernel32" ( _
ByVal CodePage As Long, _
ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
ByVal lpMultiByteStr As LongPtr, _
ByVal cchMultiByte As Long, _
ByVal lpWideCharStr As LongPtr, _
ByVal cchWideChar As Long _
) As Long

' CodePage constant for UTF-8
Private Const CP_UTF8 = 65001

''' Return length of byte array or zero if uninitialized
Private Function BytesLength(abBytes() As Byte) As Long
    ' Trap error if array is uninitialized
    On Error Resume Next
    BytesLength = UBound(abBytes) - LBound(abBytes) + 1
End Function

''' Return VBA "Unicode" string from byte array encoded in UTF-8
Public Function Utf8BytesToString(abUtf8Array() As Byte) As String
    Dim nBytes As Long
    Dim nChars As Long
    Dim strOut As String
    Utf8BytesToString = ""
    ' Catch uninitialized input array
    nBytes = BytesLength(abUtf8Array)
    If nBytes <= 0 Then Exit Function
    ' Get number of characters in output string
    nChars = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0&, VarPtr(abUtf8Array(0)), nBytes, 0&, 0&)
    ' Dimension output buffer to receive string
    strOut = String(nChars, 0)
    nChars = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0&, VarPtr(abUtf8Array(0)), nBytes, StrPtr(strOut), nChars)
    Utf8BytesToString = Left$(strOut, nChars)
End Function

'Grabbed from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798759/how-convert-hex-string-into-byte-array-in-vb6
Private Function HexToBytes(ByVal HexString As String) As Byte()
    'Quick and dirty hex String to Byte array.  Accepts:
    '
    '   "HH HH HH"
    '   "HHHHHH"
    '   "H HH H"
    '   "HH,HH,     HH" and so on.

    Dim Bytes() As Byte
    Dim HexPos As Integer
    Dim HexDigit As Integer
    Dim BytePos As Integer
    Dim Digits As Integer

    ReDim Bytes(Len(HexString) \ 2)  'Initial estimate.
    For HexPos = 1 To Len(HexString)
        HexDigit = InStr("0123456789ABCDEF", _
                         UCase$(Mid$(HexString, HexPos, 1))) - 1
        If HexDigit >= 0 Then
            If BytePos > UBound(Bytes) Then
                'Add some room, we'll add room for 4 more to decrease
                'how often we end up doing this expensive step:
                ReDim Preserve Bytes(UBound(Bytes) + 4)
            End If
            Bytes(BytePos) = Bytes(BytePos) * &H10 + HexDigit
            Digits = Digits + 1
        End If
        If Digits = 2 Or HexDigit < 0 Then
            If Digits > 0 Then BytePos = BytePos + 1
            Digits = 0
        End If
    Next
    If Digits = 0 Then BytePos = BytePos - 1
    If BytePos < 0 Then
        Bytes = "" 'Empty.
    Else
        ReDim Preserve Bytes(BytePos)
    End If
    HexToBytes = Bytes
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
Public Sub ExampleLock()
    Dim LockBytes()  As Byte
    LockBytes = HexToBytes("F0 9F 94 92") ' Lock Hex representation, found by -->http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Utf8BytesToString(LockBytes) ' Output
End Sub
```

Here's what is outputting to A1.

[image: Lock]

Comment: That's... bounty-worthy awesome!

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated

Comment: Just as a FYI - this may not work in all places. For example, this might not work in a VBA `MsgBox` even though it should support Unicode. I ---think--- speculate that is due to the fact that VB* system uses [UCS-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set) to implement Unicode support and this is only limited to 65K code points as explained in that article.

Comment: [Works in legacy in-cell comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKhEG.png)!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon OMG, lol. As an FYI, you may need to adjust the call to `MultiByteToWideChar` for 32/64 bitness.

Comment: Wonderful example, much appreciated +1. Will update to current PtrSafe API functions and needed datatypes, too :-)

Comment: @RyanWildry, suppose the key to success is changing the `lpWideCharStr` from `String` to `Long` as variable `LockBytes` is interpreted as `Bytes` data type.

Comment: @T.M. Here's the API details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar. lpWideChatStr is of type `LPWSTR` (aka Long Pointer Wide String, I think), which is defined here --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/50e9ef83-d6fd-4e22-a34a-2c6b4e3c24f3. They'll do a better job explaining this. Hope it helps!

Comment: Only felt a shadow of incertainty as MS proposes a **`String`** type for the `lpWidCharStr` argument, i.e. `Declare PtrSafe Function MultiByteToWideChar Lib "kernel32" (
    ByVal CodePage As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long,
    ByVal cchMultiByte As Long, ByVal lpWideCharStr As STRING, ByVal cchWideChar As Long) As Long` in its *VBA document* [Office2010Win32API_PtrSafe Declare statements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=9970) *with download into folder C:\Office 2010 Developer Resources\Documents\Office2010Win32API_PtrSafe.*

Comment: I'll leave the bounty up for a couple of days for exposure - this answer deserves it.

Comment: passing the value as string is just too wasteful. A `Long` would suffice

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks so much! Blown away :)

Answer (score 8):

The function that works for Unicode characters outside the basic multilingual plane (BMP) is `WorksheetFunction.Unichar()`. This example converts cells containing hexadecimal into their Unicode equivalent:

```
Sub Convert()
    For i = 1 To Selection.Cells.Count
        n = WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Selection.Cells(i).Text)
        Selection.Cells(i) = WorksheetFunction.Unichar(n)
    Next
End Sub
```

Original selection before running macro:

[image: Two cells selected with text 1f512 and 1f513]

After running macro:

[image: Images of Unicode LOCK and OPEN LOCK symbols]

If your Excel is older and `WorksheetFunction` is not available, building UTF-16 surrogates manually works, too:

```
Sub Convert()
    For i = 1 To Selection.Cells.Count
        n = CLng("&H" + Selection.Cells(i).Text) 'Convert hexadecimal text to integer
        If n < &H10000 Then 'BMP characters
            Selection.Cells(i) = ChrW(n)
        Else
            'UTF-16 hi/lo surrogate conversion
            'Algorithm:
            '1. Code point - 10000h (max U+10FFFF give 9FFFF...20 bits)
            '2. In binary, but 10 bits in first surrogate (x) and 10 in 2nd surrogate (y)
            '   110110xxxxxxxxxx 110111yyyyyyyyyy
            tmp = n - &H10000
            h = &HD800 + Int(tmp / (2 ^ 10)) 'bitwise right shift by 10
            l = &HDC00 + (tmp And &H3FF)     'bitwise AND of last 10 bits
            Selection.Cells(i) = ChrW(h) + ChrW(l)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm overwhelmed as I didn't expect a second valid answer, appreciate very much :-)

Comment: Didn't think to find another vaild answer; found a 3rd solution via HTML, too :-) @MarkTolonen

Comment: @T.M. Edited with a more succinct solution.

Answer (score 4):

as an alternative to T.M.

*Don't forget to add a reference to 'Microsoft HTML Object Library'*

```
Function GetUnicode(CharCodeString As String) As String
    Dim Doc As New HTMLDocument
    Doc.body.innerHTML = "&#x" & CharCodeString & ";"
    GetUnicode = Doc.body.innerText
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Following is a VBScript code that I use in ASP Classic.

As you'll notice, there's no type declarations, everything is variant.
What I intended to do with it was having a `ChrU` and `AscU` functions supporting characters beyond UCS-2 (Basic Multilingual Plane).

Since this is written for VBScript first, I think it's quite host-agnostic. Don't have one, but it should work on MACs too. Hope it helps.

[image: AscU and ChrU in VBx]

```vb
Private Function RightShift(ByVal pVal, shift)
    Dim i, nVal
    For i = 1 To shift
        nVal = (pVal And &H7FFFFFFF) \ 2
        If nVal And &H80000000 Then nVal = nVal Or &HC0000000
        pVal = nVal
    Next
    RightShift = pVal
End Function

Private Function LeftShift(ByVal pVal, shift)
    Dim i, nVal
    For i = 1 To shift
        nVal = (pVal And &H3FFFFFFF) * 2
        If pVal And &H40000000 Then
            nVal = nVal Or &H80000000
        End If
        pVal = nVal
    Next
    LeftShift = nVal
End Function

Public Function ChrU(ByVal code)
    Dim lo, hi ' to hold 16-bit surrogate pairs

    code = Int(code)
    If code <= 65535 Then
        ' code is in the UCS-2 range (a.k.a. Basic Multilingual Plane) which ChrW (and AscW) relies on.
        ' falling back to ChrW
        ChrU = ChrW(code)
    ElseIf code <= 1114111 Then ' code is in the Unicode range beyond UCS-2
        code = code - &H10000
        lo = ChrW(&HD800& Or RightShift(code, 10))
        hi = ChrW(&HDC00& Or (code And &H3FF))
        ChrU = Join(Array(lo, hi), "")
    Else
        Err.Raise 9, "ChrU", "Code point was out of range."
    End If
End Function

Public Function AscU(str)
    Dim lo, hi ' to hold 16-bit surrogate pairs

    If Len(str) = 1 Then
        AscU = AscW(str) And &HFFFF&
    Else
        Dim txt

        txt = Left(str, 2)
        lo = AscW(Mid(txt, 1, 1)) And &HFFFF&
        hi = AscW(Mid(txt, 2, 1)) And &HFFFF&

        If &HDC00& > hi Or hi > &HDFFF& Then
            ' hi surrogate is not valid
            ' assuming "str" is a Unicode (UCS-2) string of at least 2 characters
            ' returning first character's codepoint
            ' as Asc and AscW do
            AscU = lo
            Exit Function
        End If

        AscU = &H10000 + LeftShift(lo And &H3FF, 10) + (hi And &H3FF)
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

**Work around via HTML**

Just in addition to the valid solutions above: I found an easy work around using *IE HTML* content, as HTML is not distinguishing between lower and higher code block sets; the function below simply returns the interpreted *inner html*:

**Example call writing a padlock symbol e.g. to cell `A1`**

```
[A1] = GetUnicode("1F512")
```

**[1] Function GetUnicode() - via InternetExplorer**

```
Function GetUnicode$(ByVal CharCodeString$)
' Purpose: get Unicode character via any valid unprefixed hex code string
' Note:    late bound InternetExplorer reference
Dim Ie As Object
Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With Ie
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    .document.body.innerhtml = "&#x" & CharCodeString & ";"  ' prefixing HTML code
    GetUnicode = .document.body.innerhtml
   .Quit
End With
End Function
```

**[2a] Alternative Function GetUnicode() - via XMLDom (Edit 5/12 2019)**

This represents a host agnostic approach using XMLDom. Citing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

> "The Document Object Model (DOM) is a cross-platform and language-independent application programming interface that treats an XML document as a tree structure wherein each node is an object representing a part of the document. "

Similar to the IE approach the Unicode entity consists of the numeric (hex) prefix `&#x` + num + `;`. Generally I love XML as it allows generally a more flexible coding via its individual node and sub-node references; this example only demonstrates the simplest way to give an idea.

```
Function getUnicode$(ByVal CharCodeString$)
' Purpose: get Unicode character via any valid unprefixed hex code string
' Note:    late bound MSXML2 reference using XMLDom
Dim XmlString$
XmlString = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><root><symbol>&#x" _
    & CharCodeString & ";</symbol></root>"
With CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    .ValidateOnParse = True
    .Async = False
    If .LoadXML(XmlString) Then
        getUnicode = .DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("symbol").Text
    End If
End With
End Function
```

**[2b] Further approach using `FilterXML` - late edit as of 12/29 2019**

The WorksheetFunction `FilterXML` added in Excel 2013 allows to reformulate and shorten the above code as follows:

```
Function getUnicode$(ByVal CharCodeString$)
' Purpose: get Unicode character via any valid unprefixed hex code string
' Note:    the FilterXML() function was introduced by Version 2013
' Help:    https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.filterxml  
Dim XmlString As String
XmlString = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><root><symbol>&#x" _
    & CharCodeString & ";</symbol></root>"
getUnicode = Application.WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(XmlString, "//symbol")
End Function
```

**Addendum** *(5/2 2021)*

Using the above `FilterXML()` function you can also omit the **XML declaration** `<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>`:

Excel and generally any XML parser assumes that the encoding is UTF-8 or UTF-16 if an XML document lacks encoding specification (unless the encoding has already been determined by a higher protocol). So you could even truncate the above function to

```
Function getUnicode$(ByVal hex$)
    getUnicode = Application.WorksheetFunction.FilterXML("<r><s>&#x" & hex & ";</s></r>", "//s")
End Function
```

**Note** *that any node names can be used instead of the above tags `<r>` (for `<root>`) or `s` (for `<symbol>`).*