# Under what circumstances would VBA data type "Byte" be useful?

Tags: excel, vba, binary

Being relatively new to VBA and on the back of advice I've been given on this site, I'm trying to get in the habit of specifying data types when I code. I've been looking at the data types listed on the following webpage and thought about the scenarios in which each data type might be used:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary

However, I have a question about how `Byte` might be used. In which scenarios would it be preferable to use `Byte` over other data types? In other words: When would a 0 -255 data range be advantageous?

I'm not getting too caught up in data types but definitely curious about this one!

Comment: When something requires a byte datatype. In C, strings are arrays of characters which are/were bytes. In VBA you can use byte arrays as strings, ie pass Unicode in a byte array or store binary data in a byte array. To set up a accelerator key see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms646340. Also there is no memory saving for using a byte to hold 0-255. Variables are aligned on 4 byte boundaries unless a string or byte array.

Comment: `Dim MyArray() as Byte:MyArray = "Cat"` puts a Unicode word called Cat into a byte array. To use it instead of a string pass the first byte - `MyAPIFunction(MyArray(0))` (which is what VBA does for strings, passes the first byte). VBA converts all Unicode strings to ANSI when you call an API function. Using byte arrays allows you to use Windows' Unicode functions in the API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For most casual things, you don't need a `Byte` data type - even if the values you intend to use are within `Byte` range.

You don't typicaly *need* a 16-bit `Integer` either for that matter - whenever you need an integer type in VBA, a `Long` (32-bit, signed integer) is ideal, and consuming more bytes than you really need isn't a concern when available memory is measured in *Giga*bytes... which wasn't exactly the case in 1993.

Rule of thumb, if you need an integer type, use a `Long`; modern processors are optimized for working with 32-bit integers, and [internally there's no difference whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/1188513), so using `Byte` for values that fit 8-bit integers, `Integer` for values that fit a 16-bit integer, and `Long` for values that fit a 32-bit integer, ...is really just useless additional work that isn't saving any memory.

`Byte` is a low-level data type very often used with arrays, that is useful for things like dealing with [string encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56008649/1188513), for example.

Some standard library functions work better with `Byte` values; `VBA.Information.RGB` comes to mind:

[image: Function RGB(Red As Integer, Green As Integer, Blue As Integer) As Long]

While the function is happy to work with any `Integer`, any argument value greater than 255 will cap at 255, so `RGB(1000, 0, 0)` outputs `255`: feeding it with `Byte` values kind of makes sense then, but only for self-documentation purposes - nothing to do with memory consumption.

Comment: The most common use of Byte is likely to be arrays of them, given that it's the way to store absolutely any type of data that has no corresponding/matching built-in type.

Comment: @AlexK. absolutely!

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, you're a star!

Answer (score 2):

VBA isn't dedicated to Excel. Think about Access (to stay within Office tools).
When you plan to store a million rows in a table, you might want to use a `Byte` for some fields. You can then read your `Byte` field into a `Byte` variable.
As @Matthieu said, for Excel it has little value.
Keep in mind also that `And` and `Or` are bitwise operations in VBA. I already used `Byte` + bitwise operators to check for permissions, for example.